# Validate Lead RecordType matches Target Opportunity Record Type before Converting

Tags: validation-rule, lead-conversion

**Scenario**

We have two types of opportunities and two types of leads. The two opps are for different business processes related to the customers specific needs.

We currently have sales agents able to convert a Lead of Record Type 1 into Opps with a record type 2. This is causing problems with the customer data once the sales agent moves to the existing opp and begins the sales process.

As a result they have to create a new opportunity and change the record type manually and fix the opp that way.

We would like to use a validation rule on the opportunity to fix this problem. Here is what I have so far:

```
AND(ISNEW(),
NOT(Original_Lead__r.RecordType.DeveloperName = 
RecordType.DeveloperName)
)
```

This will fire on initial conversion, but let's say the customer needs a second opportunity of record type 2 *after conversion*, the rule will still fire and prevent its creation. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: At this point I'm thinking this is going to have to either be handled in the trigger or in a VisualForce page. Anyone else agree?

Answer (score 1):

An approach:

- use a Process Builder to set the `Lead.RecordType.DeveloperName` into a text field on Lead called `RecordType_DevName__c`
- Using Lead mapping rules, assign this field to an Opportunity field called `Sourced_From_Lead_RecordType__c`
- Use a Process Builder on Opportunity to coerce the Opportunity recordtype to the desired record type

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying use the ProcessBuilder then to check 'Source_From_Lead_RecordType__' and then on create of opportunity, we would set the record type to match?

Comment: The act of lead conversion will execute DML on Opportunity so PB on Opportunity can execute and exploit any fields mapped from Lead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We were able to figure it out with a workaround...posting now.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the ISNEW() did not work. Worked with our sr. dev and we were able to get this workaround.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(RecordTypeId)),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Original_Lead__c)),
    Original_Lead__r.RecordType.DeveloperName != RecordType.DeveloperName ,
    Original_Lead__r.ConvertedOpportunityId = Id,
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'
)
```

We added the profile filter at the end in case we needed to fix leads for our agents. Thanks for the help.